# Need to automate disk utlization in mongo db kubernetics

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongodb-query, kubectl

Need to write below disk utilization script:

```
[b807@zp242 ~]$ ./kubectl config use-context agff
Switched to context "agff".
[b07@zp242 ~]$  ./kubectl exec -it agff-2 -c mongo bash
bash-4.2$  df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
ovlay                            542G   15G  500G   3% /
tmpfs                               61M     0   61M   0% /dev
tmpfs                              234G     0  234G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/map/data_vg-vol2          542G   15G  500G   3% /data
/dev/map/data1_vg-shared_vol29  2.1T  1.4T  585G  85% /data/db
```

Tried to write the script with below commands:
say for ex: diskutl.sh

```
./kubectl config use-context agff
 ./kubectl exec -it agff-2 -c mongo bash
df -h
```

suggestion is this correct to write script in kubernetics env.
need to monitor the disk utlization for file system: /data/db only

Also tried with :

```
./kubectl exec -it agff-2  -c mongo bash  -- df -h
```

/usr/bin/df: /usr/bin/df: cannot execute binary file
command terminated with exit code 126

any suggestions, on how can we schedule the script for  disk utilization using above code.

Comment: Mongo exposes storage stats in `db.stats()` command, might suit your needs better?

Comment: Thanks, Plancke,  after writing above commands in script and running: on command prompt bash-4.2$   is  coming and not runing df-h or db.stats()

Comment: `db.stats()` is a mongo command, so you just connect to the replica set you want info from with a mongo client and run the command there. Then you don't have to worry about connecting to containers with shells

Comment: ok thanks Plancke, but we need only disk utlization for filesystem /data/db from above so using this in script: ./kubectl config use-context agff
 ./kubectl exec -it agff-2 -c mongo bash
df -h but  df -h is not getting executed.

Comment: Your script tries to launch an interactive debugging shell in the pod, and after that returns, it runs `df -h` on the local system.  Could you potentially rewrite this sequence into a single command (without `bash`)?

Comment: (Using Kubernetes- or MongoDB-native statistics plus a metric-collection system like Prometheus would probably be preferable to the approach you're describing here.)

Comment: Also tried with :

./kubectl exec -it agff-2  -c mongo bash  -- df -h
/usr/bin/df: /usr/bin/df: cannot execute binary file command terminated with exit code 126

Comment: ./kubectl exec -it agff-2  -c mongo bash  -- df -h
/usr/bin/df: /usr/bin/df: cannot execute binary file command terminated with exit code 126

any suggestions, on how can we schedule the script for disk utilization using above code.